# fetch data in to table and update- when edit click not only one value select

Tags: php, mysql

I select data from `reg_data3` and fetch to table and want to update but when update click only it is not work well. 
please help me

```
$sql= 'select date,temp_air, dry_temp,wet_temp,rel_humid, soil_temp_5,soil_temp_20,soil_temp_30,soil_temp_60, air_pressure from reg_data2'; 
$query=mysql_query($sql); 
if(!isset($_GET['ch']) ){ 
    echo '<table border="1">'; 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['temp_air'].'</td>';echo '<td>'.$row['dry_temp'].'</td>';echo '<td>'.$row['wet_temp'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['rel_humid'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['soil_temp_5'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['soil_temp_20'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['soil_temp_30'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['soil_temp_60'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['air_pressure'].'</td>'; echo '<td><a href="manage_sess_data.php?edit='.$row['date'].'& ch=ch">edit</a></td>'; echo '<td><a href="manage_sess_data.php?delete='.$row['date'].'& ch=ch">delete</a></td>'; echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
} else if(isset($_GET['edit'])){ 
    $date=$_GET['edit']; 
    echo $sqlup= 'select date,temp_air,dry_temp, wet_temp,rel_humid,soil_temp_5, soil_temp_20,soil_temp_30,soil_temp_60,air_pressure from reg_data2 where date="'.$date.'"'; 
    $queryup=mysql_query($sql); while($uprow=mysql_fetch_array($queryup)){ 
    $temp_air=$uprow['temp_air']; $dry_temp=$uprow['dry_temp']; 
    $wet_temp=$uprow['wet_temp']; $rel_humid=$uprow['rel_humid'];
}
    echo '<form action="manage_sess_data.php?update=up & ch=ch & day='.$date.'" method="post">'; echo '<p>Temp air:<input type="text" value="'.$temp_air.'" name="temp_air"></p>'; 
    echo '<p>dry_temp:<input type="text" value="'.$dry_temp.'" name="dry_temp"></p>'; echo '<p>wet_temp:<input type="text" value="'.$wet_temp.'" name="wet_temp"></p>'; echo '<p>rel_humid:<input type="text" value="'.$rel_humid.'" name="rel_humid"></p>';
    echo'<input type="submit" value="update" name="update"></form>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will passing row id in edit button something like this

```
echo '<td><a href="manage_sess_data.php?id='.$row['id'].'">edit</a></td>';
```

after that get id value from url with

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

use this id to query

```
$query="UPDATE tablename SET fieldname='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
```